# Why is it not a acceptable answer in code chef test : TLG

Tags: python, python-3.x

I came across the following question on codechef and solved it in different ways, but the second way (refer code 2) is not accepted as an answer. Do I miss any test case?

> The game of billiards involves two players knocking 3 balls around on
> a green baize table. Well, there is more to it, but for our purposes
> this is sufficient.
>
> The game consists of several rounds and in each round both players
> obtain a score, based on how well they played. Once all the rounds
> have been played, the total score of each player is determined by
> adding up the scores in all the rounds and the player with the higher
> total score is declared the winner.
>
> The Siruseri Sports Club organises an annual billiards game where the
> top two players of Siruseri play against each other. The Manager of
> Siruseri Sports Club decided to add his own twist to the game by
> changing the rules for determining the winner. In his version, at the
> end of each round, the cumulative score for each player is calculated,
> and the leader and her current lead are found. Once all the rounds are
> over the player who had the maximum lead at the end of any round in
> the game is declared the winner.
>
> Consider the following score sheet for a game with 5 rounds:
>
> ```
> Round | Player 1 | Player 2
> 1     | 140      | 82
> 2     | 89       | 134 
> 3     | 90       | 110
> 4     | 112      | 106  
> 5     | 88       | 90
> ```
>
> The total scores of both players, the leader and the lead after each
> round for this game is given below:
>
> ```
> Round | Player 1 | Player 2 | Leader   | Lead
> 1     | 140      | 82       | Player 1 | 58 
> 2     | 89       | 134      | Player 1 | 13
> 3     | 90       | 110      | Player 2 | 7
> 4     | 112      | 106      | Player 2 | 1
> 5     | 88       | 90       | Player 2 | 3
> ```
>
> Note that the above table contains the cumulative scores.
>
> The winner of this game is Player 1 as he had the maximum lead (58 at
> the end of round 1) during the game.
>
> Your task is to help the Manager find the winner and the winning lead.
> You may assume that the scores will be such that there will always be
> a single winner. That is, there are no ties.
>
> **Input**
>
> The first line of the input will contain a single integer N (N ≤
> 10000) indicating the number of rounds in the game. Lines 2,3,...,N+1
> describe the scores of the two players in the N rounds. Line i+1
> contains two integer Si and Ti, the scores of the Player 1 and 2
> respectively, in round i. You may assume that 1 ≤ Si ≤ 1000 and 1 ≤ Ti
> ≤ 1000.
>
> **Output**
>
> Your output must consist of a single line containing two integers W
> and L, where W is 1 or 2 and indicates the winner and L is the maximum
> lead attained by the winner.
>
> **Example**
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> 5
> 140 82
> 89 134
> 90 110
> 112 106
> 88 90
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> 1 58
> ```

The following code is accepted by Codechef, which gives output: `1 58`

**Code 1:**

```
n = int(input())
player1 = 0
player2 = 0
lead = 0

for i in range(n):
    score1, score2 = map(int, input().split())
    player1 += score1
    player2 += score2
    diff = player1 - player2
    if player1 > player2 and diff > lead:
        lead = diff
        leader = 1
    if player2 > player1 and abs(diff) > lead:
       lead = abs(diff)
       leader = 2
print(leader, lead)
```

The same output, `1 58`, is obtained using below code but not accepted as answer in code chef.

Which test case am I not satisfying which is making my code as not acceptable?

**Code 2:**

```
a = int(input())

player1 = 1
player2 = 2

lst = []
cummulative_score = []
for i in range(a):
    b, c = map(int, input().split())
    lst.append([b, c])

for k, j in lst:
    if k > j:
       cummulative_score.append([int(player1), k - j])
    else:
       cummulative_score.append([int(player2), j - k])

max_lead = sorted(cummulative_score, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[0]
winner = int(max_lead[0])
lead = int(max_lead[1])
print(winner, lead)
```

Comment: code chef uses more then this _one_ test case you passed ... and for some of them the input might be MUCH BIGGER (up to 10000 according to your specs) so your code is too slow to pass - then you fail. even if it is not too slow  you may loose by using to much memory if it is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your code fails for this case:

```
4
1 2
1 2
1 2
3 1
```

Your code outputs:

```
1 2
```

But the correct output is:

```
2 3
```

The error in your code is that you don't accumulate the scores. Your code compares the difference of individual `k` and `j`, but should really compare the *running sums* of these values.

To fix it, replace this line:

```
for k, j in lst:
```

with:

```
k = j = 0
for a, b in lst:
    k += a
    j += b
```

Still, it is quite inefficient to build a list and *sort* it, as you don't really need the sorted result, ... just the maximum value.

Comment: How come it is 2 ,3 can you elaborate how you are getting 2 ,3

Comment: After the first 3 rounds, the first player has accumulated 3 points, while the second player has accumulated 6 points. So at that moment, the second player is 3 points ahead. This record is never beaten, so the answer is `2 3`, ie. player 2 wins with 3 points (difference).

Comment: @trincot : Seems like he is a new user , may be he thought multiple solution can be upvoted